# How do I achieve this tessellated effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm currently recreating Image 1, but finding it hard to lay down the finishing touches, namely, the triangular pattern that encompasses the hexagon. My progress can be seen in Image 2, and my design method can be seen at this link: http://gyazo.com/45b34f3810808364be3fd66584b581e8. I am currently using Photoshop CS6. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Original image]

[image: My current recreation]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! I would not use Photoshop for this, but rather 
*Illustrator* instead, as theres not much point in doing pure vector graphics is Photoshop. What seems to be the problem? Are you asking how to draw two triangles per side?

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. As simple as it sounds, that's exactly what I'm asking. I'm having trouble drawing triangles that fit together perfectly. I'm currently attempting this with the polygon tool. Is there a better alternative, or is this simply a case of trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a rectangle and a triangle for each side of the internal hexagon using a darker shade of blue, then set the opacity of the layer to 50%.

You can move the corners of shapes around by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click and drag on a corner to move it around.

**Note:** You should use guides to help align each triangle and rectangle.

The red dots in the image below show the positions of the rectangle's corners and the green dots show the triangle's corner positions.

[image: Arrangement of shape corners]

[image: Result]

Comment: As you see the triangle is a bit off since the shape its not  in right proportion Almost but not quite

Comment: I see... It would work better if you had guides on the edges and vertices of the hexagons.

Comment: A simple and easy to do solution! Worked perfectly, many thanks.

Comment: It would help to have a triangle grid to snap to yes.

Comment: The danger here is that it may now nolonger be a perfect hexagon. Anyway now your image is correct theres actually no explanation on how you did it in the post.

Comment: Still not entirely there you still need to ensure that the edges also align to this proportion so the original lines need to align to those proportions too or it wont work. It happens to work because the user is copying the geometry but it wouldn't work very well if he was not having the right proportions but i guess it suffices for this question

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a bit tricky. That is because the shape will not work if the proportion is not correct. You may need to start over if you dont happen to be extremely lucky. As **@polarity** first answer shows your almost right but the triangles that a bit slanted because its not quite right and the tessellation does not become symmetric as a result.

Start your drawing with a triangle.

[image]

Rotate that triangle about its center, triangle center NOT bounding box center. Tip: It may be wise to put guides in this place first.

[image]

Duplicate triangle edges to the corner of triangle (this ensures you match up)

[image]

Trim and find the triangle edge center for the mid lines

[image]

All that's left is rounding corners and drawing the one line to the for the second triangle. Now I wasn't really exact enough, so i would have have to start over again... Better pay attention next time. A isometric/triangle grid might help doing this...